# Trying to do a simple regular expression to match 7 digits or 9 digits. No solutions I've found actually work

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I'm extracting a string of numbers  The numbers are either 7 digits or they are 9 digits.  Exactly 7, or exactly 9.  If it's 8 or its 10 I don't want it to extract anything.   I've tried looking on here and none of the expressions are working for me. I've tried the following.

```
/[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{9}/
```

-- This gives me the first 7 digits only.  If it is 8 digits or 9 digits I only get the first 7.

```
/[0-9]{7}([0-9]{2})?/
```

-- Will give me 7 digits.  If it is 8 digits it gives me the first 7.  If it is 9 digits it gives me 9.  I need only 7, or only 9.

```
/^(\d{7}|\d{9})$/
```

-- Doesn't work at all unless I remove the caret and the $, and then it works just like the first expression example.

I don't understand why | as an "or" isn't working.

I know \d is the modern regex shorthand, but the application cannot compile that way.  I get an error saying "Don't escape other characters than of "[].\ (){}?+*<>|^"." .

Comment: This will match 7 or 9 digits `^\d{7}(?:\d{2})?$`

Comment: I get the following result. 
Can't compile Regular Expression:
Can't parse cardinality at this position. Got stuck with: "?:[0-9]{2}"

Again, I have to change "\d" to old school "[0-9]" as it thinks I'm trying to escape characters.

Comment: /[^\d][0-9]{7}[^\d]|[^\d][0-9]{9}[^\d]/

Comment: So close.  This works for 9 digits, but doesn't give me a value if the string is 7 digits.  This will also give me the first 9 digits if the string is more than 9 digits.

Comment: Use numeric boundaries, `(?<!\d)\d{7}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)`

Comment: Can't compile Regular Expression:  
Can't parse cardinality at this position. Got stuck with: "?<!\d"

Comment: This Almost works.  /[0-9]{7}([0-9]{2})?/    If the test is 7 digits I get 7.  If the test is 9 digits I get 9.  BUT if the test is 8 digits I get the first 7.   Is there a way to make it not extract if it is 8 digits?